# new jest user confused with correct way to mock a node module in typescript

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, typesafe-actions

Hi I am a new jest user using jest within a Typescript environment.

From reading the [jest guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules), if I want to mock a node module  I need to create a file with the module name within a `__mocks__` folder so that jest will import the mocked module. For example, if I want to mock the *typesafe-actions* library then I would have:

src ->  `__mocks__` -> typesafe-actions.ts

```js
// __mocks__/typesafe-actions.ts
'use strict';

const typesafe = jest.genMockFromModule('typesafe-actions');

(typesafe as any).createAsyncAction = jest.fn();

module.exports = typesafe;
```

After doing this, I have found that tests break that require the actual module implementation to be imported, with function undefined errors. I fixed this by issuing a `jest.unmock('typesafe-actions')` statement in the header of test files that require the actual module implementation. This is because the test files:

- do a direct import of the module or
- an indirect import via another module.

Am I doing this correctly, or is there a better way?

In the test file that uses the mock I am receiving an error that `createAction` is not a function...how do I correctly mock one function from a library and leave the remaining module functions functions untouched?